# What is the missing parameter in TaskState<TResult> in Bolts-Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, bolts-framework

In the [Bolts-Swift](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Swift/blob/master/Sources/BoltsSwift/Task.swift) framework `Task.swift`, upgrading to Swift 4 produces this error for this method:

```
class func emptyTask() -> Task<Void> {
    return Task<Void>(state: .success())
}
```

The error states:

> Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

I understand that it's saying `.success` needs to take a parameter but without posting the entire file in here for context, can anybody with Bolts-Swift experience identify why this used to work in Swift 3 but doesn't work now using Swift 4?

Comment: Try adding TaskState into the parameter, the updated version declaration have a TResult parameter like :  return Task<Void>(state: .success(TaskState<TResult>()))
I'm trying to test if it could work well.

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @MehdiAbderezai Yes, it was an issue with the framework not being updated. It has since been resolved. See https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Swift/issues/63 for details.